# select column2 from table where column1=column3?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
KeyTable  Name  Parent
   1       n1    Null
   2       n2    Null
   3       n3     1
   4       n4     2
```

I want to `select col2 from table where col3=col1`

Comment: Where do you have col1, col2 and col3? No two cols in your data are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Well from what I see you need `join` here:

```
select
    t1.col1,
    t1.col2,
    t1.col3,
    t2.col2
from table as t1
    left outer join table as t2 on t2.col3 = col1
```

Comment: bro both of the columns KeyTable and Parent belongs to single table..

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are asking for. But I can't be sure. I suggest you spend longer time preparing your questions:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.name
FROM yourtable t1
JOIN yourtable t2
ON t1.parentid = t2.KeyTable
```

Comment: bro both of the columns KeyTable and Parent belongs to single table..

Comment: @SaqibRajpoot that is why I am giving them an alias. To join parent with child

Comment: Thanks alot, this is exactly what I want...but I got another issue

Comment: @ChiragThakar not going to remove my downvote. I still think your answer is of low quality and I don't see how correcting isnull syntax can fix it. Also someone else upvoted my downvote because they thought you had posted a good answer.

Comment: I was not being rude to you, I was upset that someone upvoted your answer. And for argument sake, your isnull will not change a thing since there are no value 0 in columns KeyTable or Parent. Do you really think your answer deserve a positive vote ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I want to show 4th column as Parent Name regarding 3rd column.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i got your Question correctly. this might help you.

```
select Name 
from Table
where isnull(KeyTable,0) = isnull(Parent,0)
```

Comment: the question doesn't make this answer correct. isnull takes 2 parameters

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Thanks, i have corrected my Mistake, Appreciate it.